# Entlib versus ACA.Net - Does ACA.Net provide any advantage?

Tags: .net, frameworks

My understanding is that Entlib has picked-up and included concepts from ACA.Net.  Is there any point to using ACA.Net on a new .net project?

Answer (score 2):

We are actively using ACA.NET 4.1 where I work.  ACA.NET actually uses EntLib at its core, and over the years Avanade have "retired" parts of their framework as EntLib functionality catches up.

One thing which EntLib doesn't do, which ACA.NET does well is its use of Aspects over a machine boundary.  I know EntLib has policy injection, but this works by manipulating the instantiation of a local object (i.e. the service).  If you want to protect your remote service with an Authorization Aspect, then an ACA.NET Aspect declared as a ReceiversOnly container will ensure the service is protected where the service runs.  If you are across physical layers on any of these service calls, ACA.NET will do the job, EntLib doesn't cut it just yet.

If your application doesn't need to be deployed to multiple physical tiers, then this advantage of ACA.NET disappears and you can fall back to use EntLib only.